# What alternatives do I have for Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: cloud-service, cloud-storage

I'm using Azure Blob Storage this way:

- User goes into the application and updates an image, voice, or video
- Metadata of that blob would be saved in my own database, on my own server
- The name of the file is changed to a GUID, to make it unique
- The blob itself is saved on the Azure Blob Storage, in a specified container, under a storage account, with the relevant file extension
- The GUID (file name) is also stored in my database in the corresponding record.
- For data retrieval, I return the record to the client (web,android,ios) and also inflate the return value with the complete URL to the azure storage, like:

https://iqraa.blob.core.windows.net/pronunciations/a763d66e-4e37-434e-b496-5fda4985c4d4.mp3

However, now a business customer wants us to use another service, as a fail-over for Azure Blob Storage. I know that Azure is robust, but this is requirement that we store each blob on Azure, and on another service at the same time.

There are other services, like http://alternativeto.net/software/azure-storage/

Yet they seem to be for **online storage** of an ordinary user like Dropbox, not for programmatic upload and direct access via browsers and smartphones.

What other alternatives do we have and can we use that is like Azure Blob Storage, and gives us direct public access to files saved on it, programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

If failover is your concern, you can change your blob storage to Read-access **geo-redundant storage (RA-GRS)**, so your data will be stored in secondary geographic place and will solve the failure problems. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-introduction#replication-for-durability-and-high-availability

If you want to go big leap then, you can choose **Amazon's Simple storage**

http://gauravmantri.com/2012/05/13/comparing-windows-azure-blob-storage-and-amazon-simple-storage-service-s3summary/

Answer (score 0):

You should look at object storage cloud providers. Most of them are using S3 API or other non-Azure interface , so you’ll need to adjust a code a little bit. Check the followings:

[Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/?nc1=h_ls)

[Wasabi](https://wasabi.com/)

[Backblaze B2](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/cloud-storage.html)

[Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage)

[Alibaba Storage](https://www.alibabacloud.com/product/oss?spm=a3c0i.272861.1389108.dnavproductstorage1.16c324afi8VG3d)

IMHO, I’d use Amazon S3, if higher price is affordable. Or Wasabi with limited budget.
Here are some link with enterprise cloud storage comparasions:

http://gaul.org/object-store-comparison/

https://www.vmwareblog.org/looking-affordable-cloud-storage-aws-vs-azure-vs-backblaze-b2/

https://medium.com/@simon_80033/how-cheap-can-cloud-storage-be-8262c67b48c1