# Alternatives to Azure Blob Storage with cheap/unlimited writes

Tags: cloud-service, cloud-storage

There is a similar topic here - [What alternatives do I have for Azure Blob Storage?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/42131/what-alternatives-do-i-have-for-azure-blob-storage) - but it does not answer my question.

I have several servers (in different countries) which all need to read/write to a shared file storage.

I am uzing Azure Blob Storage right now, and while the price per GB is small, the write operations are very expensive (0.05 USD per 10,000 writes).

The files are tiny, but my application writes to the files very frequently, so the costs are soaring.

What would be an alternative similar to Azure Blob Storage, but with cheap or unlimited writes?

Comment: Have you checked what Amazon offers?

Comment: @JanDoggen Yes, the pricing of Amazon Simple Storage Service is exactly the same as Azure's. 0.05 USD per 10000 writes.